# Lenthy Latex formulae are submerged to the right of the page

Tags: automatic

In the align environment of Latex, my expression is too long.
The align environment cannot automatically give line break, so part
of my expression is submerged to the right of the page.
Is there some other environment in Latex that can automatically line break?

As my expression is too lengthy, doing line-break by hand is unrealistic.

I tried mutiline environment， but it did not work.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...